# Why is my loading animation appearing only at the top with the full website still visable?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Website works. But the loading animation appears at the top. Everything works fine. Except this. I have no clue why its happening. I thought it was because the loading screen was inside the body scope or something. I tried rearranging everything with the container of the loading screen in the middle. but that made the website wonky.

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="bowl">
      <div class="glow"></div>
      <div class="glow glow-a"></div>
      <div class="glow glow-b"></div>

    </div>
  </div>

<div class="divclass">
    <div class="item">
    <h2  class="subitem"> test heading</h2>
    </div>

<script>
  $(window).on("load",function(){
    $(".container").fadeOut("slow");
  });

</script>
```

CSS

```
.container{
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.bowl{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  background: #00F260;  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to top, #0575E6 -80%, #00F260);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #0575E6 -80%, #00F260); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
  position: relative;
  z-index: 300;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.glow{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-left: -50px;
  background: #000;
  margin-top: -150px;
  border-radius: 90px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  transform-origin: 50% 48%; 
  animation: glow 5s infinite linear;
  opacity: .4;
}
.glow-a{
  background: #000;
  margin-top: -148px;
  margin-left: -58px;
  animation: glow 3s infinite linear;
  opacity:  1;
  z-index: 200;
}
.glow-b{
  opacity: .5;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  margin-top: -148px;
  animation: glow 7s infinite linear;
}
@keyframes glow {
  from{transform:rotate(0deg);  }
  from{transform:rotate(360deg);  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `position: fixed`, with high z-index, and an opaque background on the `.container` class. Also give it more height. `100vh` will cover the whole window.

```js
$(window).on("load",function(){
    $(".container").fadeOut("slow");
  });
```

```css
.container{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: white;
  z-index: 10;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.bowl{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  background: #00F260;  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to top, #0575E6 -80%, #00F260);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #0575E6 -80%, #00F260); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
  position: relative;
  z-index: 300;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.glow{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-left: -50px;
  background: #000;
  margin-top: -150px;
  border-radius: 90px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  transform-origin: 50% 48%; 
  animation: glow 5s infinite linear;
  opacity: .4;
}
.glow-a{
  background: #000;
  margin-top: -148px;
  margin-left: -58px;
  animation: glow 3s infinite linear;
  opacity:  1;
  z-index: 200;
}
.glow-b{
  opacity: .5;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  margin-top: -148px;
  animation: glow 7s infinite linear;
}
@keyframes glow {
  from{transform:rotate(0deg);  }
  from{transform:rotate(360deg);  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="bowl">
      <div class="glow"></div>
      <div class="glow glow-a"></div>
      <div class="glow glow-b"></div>

    </div>
  </div>

<div class="divclass">
    <div class="item">
    <h2  class="subitem"> test heading</h2>
    </div>
```

Comment: thank you! If you made it less than 100vh and instead of position: absolute itll mess it up? I had another problem where position absolute messed up my entire page. So I'll try avoiding it completely

Comment: Well if the user initiates a page scroll before the page is done loading,`position: absolute` will make the loader scroll with the page, not so with `fixed`. And yeah you can make it any height, `$(window).on("load")` waits until the entire page is loaded, so I thought you wanted the entire page to be obscured.